# localhost is not opening in firefox but working fine in IE8

Tags: apache, firefox, localhost

i am working in a apache web application. i completed a project with this and its working fine in IE8. Now i tried this same in firefox ,opera and chrome it results the source code.

when i typed http://localhost/, it results,

```
<html>
<head>
<title>X2A.biz</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location.href = "../pages/X2AFrame.htm"
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried with html transitional doc type also. In X2AFrame.htm, i have frameset.

can any one help in this? pls...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you didn't configure your web server correctly - it serves this page with MIME type `text/plain` instead of `text/html`. IE does content sniffing and detects that you gave it an HTML page, other browsers don't (the standard-compliant approach). So you need to fix the configuration of your web server, in Apache you can use the [AddType directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype):

```
AddType text/html .htm
```

Comment: These are the things i added in httpd.conf,                         AddType application/x-compress .Z                             AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php 
AddType text/html .htm
 
AddCharset UTF-8 .utf8

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Chrome support a Javascript debugger in them. For firefox, you can install the firebug extension, but it's already there in chrome, so :

open your page in chrome, press ctrl+shift+j to open up a javacsript debugger, and look at ther error there, it should point you in the direction of what's going wrong.

Comment: i tried in firebug. but it shows the syntax correct.>
<pre>&lt;html&gt; &lt;head&gt; &lt;title&gt;X2A.biz&lt;/title&gt; &lt;script type="text/javascript"&gt; window.location.href = "../pages/X2AFrame.htm" &lt;/script&gt; &lt;/head&gt; &lt;body&gt; &lt;/html&gt; </pre>

Comment: Anything need to change in mine.types? i already added text/html   html htm  and also i added AddType text/html .html
AddType text/html .htm in httpd.conf file.

Comment: hi wladimir  thanks for your help. ifound the error in httpd.conf file. DefaultType text/PlainTextwas there.i modified it to DefaultType text/html.now pages are opeining infirefox,chrome,opera. but one more issue CSS is not applying..

Comment: ichecked the conf file and also added,AddType text/css .cssand in mime.types also text/css css is there. But stilli am facing the css issue. can anyone help in that? pls,,,

Answer (score 0):

hi friends i found the issue...
In httpd.conf file,LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so was commented for me... thats the issue..