# Where we need place .htaccess file in apache2.2 folder?

Tags: css, apache, .htaccess, localhost

Where we need place .htaccess file in apache2.2 folder?

I already asked 2 questions related to that:

- [CSS Not Applying in localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7345881/apache-localhost-css-isnot-applying)
- [Localhost not opening in other browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332604/localhost-is-not-opening-in-firefox-but-working-fine-in-ie8)

I got the answer for the second question.. but I'm still facing the CSS issue. For that I am trying to add .htaccess file. But I don't know where I need place this file. Please any one help in this?

Currently I have added this file in "Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\conf\". But still I am facing the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi friends i found the issue...
In httpd.conf file,LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so was commented for me... thats the issue..

realy the issue is in httpd.conf file only...

Answer (score 1):

Just in the root of where ever your HTML files are will suffice.

That is unless your host has disabled htaccess files, most do now (or highly limit) due to possible security vunrabilities.

Comment: now i added this .htaccess file .. stillmy chrome debugger shows me the error "resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with mime type text plain".... what is this issue means?

Comment: @Nagarajan How do you process your CSS files? Are they processed by PHP (or any other server-side scripting language).. or served directly by Apache (in other words -- are they real files that served with no extra modifications)?